# How do I use a loop to test both an integer and the elements of a list?

Tags: python-3.x, average

I have been trying to test the argument test scores to see if any tests are below 50. If so it should return fail. If the avg is above 70 and no tests are below 50 then it should return pass.

```
def course_grader(test_scores):

    avg_grade = sum(test_scores) / len(test_scores)

    if avg_grade >= 70 and test_scores >= 50:
        print("pass")

    elif avg_grade < 70 or test_scores < 50:
        print("fail")
        break



def main():
    print(course_grader([100,75,45]))     # "fail"
    print(course_grader([100,70,85]))     # "pass"
    print(course_grader([80,60,60]))      # "fail"
    print(course_grader([80,80,90,30,80]))  # "fail"
    print(course_grader([70,70,70,70,70]))  # "pass"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also tried using a for loop but it was giving me too many answers.

Comment: `any([x<50 for x in [30,60,70]])` will yield `True`. `any([x<50 for x in [60,60,70]])` will yield `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `min(test_scores) >= 50`. If `min`is higher or equal than 50, then there is no int in `test_scores` inferior to 50.

Also, there are three issues in your code.

First, you canot use `break` statement outside of a loop. This will raise a `SyntaxError`.

Second, your function doesn't return anything you can `print`. Your `main()` will output 'pass' or 'fail' and then `None` for each `print`. You should remove the `print` in `main()` or replace them in `course_grader()` by `return`.

Finally, your `elif` can be replaced by an `else`. If `avg_grade >= 70 and test_scores >= 50` isn't `True`, then by necessity either (or both) `avg_code is < 70` or `test_score is < 50`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Bill Bell, the use of `any` or `all` functions might be useful here:

```
def course_grader(test_scores):

    avg_grade = sum(test_scores) / len(test_scores)

    if avg_grade >= 70 and all([x >= 50 for x in test_scores]):
        print("pass")

    elif avg_grade < 70 or any([x < 50 for x in test_scores]):
        print("fail")
```